# Get the maximum of printed values using python

Tags: python

I want to check a string that is available or not in a text file using python and get the similarity value. So I have a text file and first I read line by line in my text file then I checked the similarity of lines with my input string which I need to compare whether it is in or not in my text file (here apple). As below I printed lines in my text file and similarity.
Here is my text file content:

```
Apple
rose
mango
```

Here is my code:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def search_str(file_path, word):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        count=0
        for line in content:
            count += 1
            print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
            sequenceScore = SequenceMatcher(None, line.strip(), word).ratio()
            print(f"Both are {sequenceScore * 100} % similar")
            print('DP{}:{}'.format(count,sequenceScore))
           
search_str(r'C:\Users\mine\Desktop\hackrf.txt', 'apple')
```

Here is my output:

```
Line1: apple
Both are 100.0 % similar
DP1:1.0
Line2: rose
Both are 22.22222222222222 % similar
DP2:0.2222222222222222
Line3: mango
Both are 20.0 % similar
DP3:0.2
```

Now I need two print the maximum value of the sequence score (as here from DP1,DP2,DP3). But my text file can be more than three lines. So then "DP" count can also be changed. Its count can not be defined as default. It can be changed. Can anyone help me with how I can find the maximum of these values?

Comment: If you have an iterable sequence of something, you can use `max` to find the maximum value, specifying the criteria for comparison with the `key` parameter.

Comment: could you explain it furthermore?thank you

Answer (score 3):

Consider a simple example: a list of ints.

```
lst = [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```

We can find the maximum with:

```
max(lst)
```

If the comparison is not so simple, we can provide a `key` parameter to specify how to compare. If the list is a list of tuples, for instance, and we want to find the max based on the highest *second* item in the tuple:

```
lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 3)]
max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The result will be:

```
(3, 4)
```

This need not apply only to a `list`, but can be applied to any iterable sequence, including a string.

Answer (score -1):

Add a list to store the scores. Upon conclusion get the maximum value from the list.

What you want is creating an iterable (in this example a list named 'scores') before you start creating the scores, then when the looping over the file lines stops, you print the highest value with the `max()` function. Look at lines 5, 10 and 13 from this code:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def search_str(file_path, word):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        count = 0
        
        scores = []  # store scores here, an iterable list.
        
        for line in content:
            count += 1
            print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
            sequenceScore = SequenceMatcher(None, line.strip(), word).ratio()
            
            scores.append(sequenceScore) # Hold all scores 
            
            print(f"Both are {sequenceScore * 100} % similar")
            print('DP{}:{}'.format(count, sequenceScore))
        
        print(f'The highest score was {max(scores)}') # Print the highest score

search_str(r'C:\Users\mine\Desktop\hackrf.txt', 'apple')
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from elaboration.